# MVC NEt Core 5.0 - Identity help - Adding Users to database (models)

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to Net Core and studying it at the moment. I am creating a web based app for users to create events and register for these events and and need help.
I have an EventsCoordinator and Member Model which inherit from my User model which inherits from ApplicationUser : IdenityUser. In my Account Register.cshtml, I can create new users and they are added to the database in my User table, however I'd like when they select the AccountType (enum value (EventCoordinator, Member) that they will then be added to the applicable table e.g. EventsCoordinator or Member, however I am having trouble doing this. I added an IF statement but not sure what to add then...

I've yet to add roles as I want to create different levels of authorization based on these account types but that will have to try work on that later.

Any help for this newbie, would be great!

Thanks!

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new User { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email, FirstName = Input.FirstName, LastName = Input.LastName, DOB = Input.DOB, Address = Input.Address, AccountType = (Models.AccountType)Input.AccountType };
            if (AccountType == AccountType.EventCoordinator)
            {
  
            }

            else
            {

            }
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);

                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                }
                else
                {
                    await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement add the the user to the table or assign the user its role (EventCoordinator ir Member).

If EventCoordinator & Member are Roles you add the user with the UserManager.
Like
await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user,"EventCoordinator ");

If those 2 are not roles and are columns in a table in your DB
You add the users id to the specific column in your DB.

If possible specify where or how do you save the AccountType or want to save it